# how to remove the shortcut of ctrl+alt+s for gnome 42

Tags: gnome

recently I moved to gnome 42 and found that shortcut ctrl+alt+s makes current window fit to a specific window size such as 360x654, 720x360 etc.

I tried to redefine the shortcut and dug into settings menu but could not find any matching shortcuts. I guess it is hidden but not sure.

How can I find the definition or remove it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I resolved this issue by deactivating the "Screenshot Window Sizer" Gnome extension by fmuellner.

I didn't activate this stupid plugin... I was wondering, why I can't enter IntelliJ IDEA Settings by using <kbd>**CTRL**</kbd>+<kbd>**ALT**</kbd>+<kbd>**S**</kbd>

Now it works for me...

Answer (score 2):

Execute these commands in your terminal:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.shell.extensions.screenshot-window-sizer cycle-screenshot-sizes "[]"
gsettings set org.gnome.shell.extensions.screenshot-window-sizer cycle-screenshot-sizes-backward "[]"
```

That did the trick for me.